# Why dont we use the main() method in TestNG class?

Tags: automated-testing, java, testng

```
public class Tests{

  @Test
  public void run(){
    sop("this is test method 1");
  }

}
```

How will Jvm know about entry point of the program?

Answer (score 1):

Entry point is always a `main` method. If you're using command-line to run your tests, you use `org.testng.TestNG` where there is a `main` method.

If you're running tests from IDE or from Maven, there are their own main methods and at some point their code calls TestNG API to execute the tests (or call `main` method of TestNG if they run tests in different JVM)